# Internet Explorer 7 & 8 object / syntax error on JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a pretty straightforward snippet of JS/jQuery I'm using to extract some content from a page:

```
(function (idx) { 
  var product = $(".product_wrapper img")[idx]; 
  return (product && product.src) ? product.src.match(/([^]+)\\_/)[1] : "" 
}(0)).split('_')[1]
```

Works just fine in most browsers, but IE7 & IE8 are throwing errors. In IE7 the error message reads `[object Error]` and in IE8 it reads `SyntaxError: Expected '/'`.

Anybody know what's wrong with this code? Am I using some syntactic sugar that MSIE doesn't like? Been puzzling over this one and I'm stumped.

Comment: you call index `[1]` of object without Check for existence of an object?

Comment: Try splitting up the logic and trying to catch at least which line the problem is on. Instead of using one big `return` statement, split that up into `if/else` statements. Then, store the result of this immediately invoking function into a variable. Then, split that string by "_" and store that result in a new variable. Then, check the length of that new variable before accessing `[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `product.src.match(/([^]+)\\_/)` is null

`product.src.match(/([^]+)\\_/)[1]` will cause object Error

Comment: Thanks so much, @ai.farfa! It's always the obvious stuff :-) Gonna just wrap the .split inside the ternary if/else. Appreciate your help!

Comment: ...like so, for reference: `(function (idx) { var product = $(".product_wrapper img")[idx]; return (product && product.src) ? product.src.match(/([^]+)\_/)[1].split('_')[1] : "" }(0))`

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to figure out why the "better" browser, IE 8, gives its error.  The error it gives appears to refer to a missing regular expression initializer terminator, which is the '/' character (forward-slash).  Your syntax for the regular expression works on IE 9:

```
"foo".match(/([^]+)\\_/);
```

And I am pretty sure that it will work on IE 8 as well.  I recommend verifying if the above works on IE 8, and then checking to make sure that when you see the error, the code actually being run is what you have.  To verify that, you can clear the browser cache in IE 8 manually and then reload your code/webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example that breaks (at least in IE8) is this:

```
"foo".match(/[^]/);
```

The problem is that `^` in brackets means "negation" so it expects something to negate.  IE breaks because of this and it can be solved by escaping the carat (if that's what you're searching for):

```
"foo".match(/[\^]/);
```

Firefox seems to interpret `[^]` as `.` so it doesn't break.  It's unclear from your code sample what you are trying to extract from the URLs.  If you are looking for carats in the code, escape what you had in your original post.  If you are just looking for any character, as it works in firefox, use the `.` instead.

Comment: Hey Dennis. @ai.farfa (above) put it quite succinctly: I was calling `[1]` outside the ternary conditional on line 3, i.e. without testing that the object I'm trying to split exists and can be split. I think other browsers were just more forgiving of this error and didn't throw an error to the console for returning an undefined result.